# Linux box that can quickly scale to many CPUs for 5 minutes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I need a Linux box with OS such as Ubuntu.

I want to run a benchmark that uses many CPUs. I'd like something between 32 and 96. I only need 5 minutes for the benchmark. Before and afterwards I only need a dual core or so.

Which instance do I need for this?

Comment: PS: I need to run a benchmark to show how well my program scales for parallel execution.

Comment: Your question is answered by the first Google result when searching "AWS instance types".

Comment: AWS Spot Instances

Answer (score 1):

In Google cloud platform [instances are up to 96 CPU vcores](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#highcpu). It is possible to [select different architectures](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms), from Sandy Bridge up to Skylake. However if you select a cpu from over 64 cores, the only one possibility is Skylake.

Not all of the arquitectures are present in all of the regions. Here you can find a list of the regions to get to know [which architectures are available](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#available).